# How to use cookie authentication with WsFederation authentication in OWIN app

Tags: .net, authentication, cookies, owin, ws-federation

I am making an OWIN app to self host a website. I am having trouble with the authentication part. The basic flow I am looking for is:

1. Check if the request has the correct cookie. If it has the correct cookie, then get the `SecuritySessionToken` and build the `ClaimsIdentity`, and then return the `AuthenticationTicket`.
2. If the cookie isn't there, then let the STS know.
3. Get the SAML token from the STS and build the claims & authentication ticket. (Even though I'm using WsFederation authentication, ADFS is not involved here.)

**Step 1 is working fine for me. Steps 2 and 3 are where I'm having trouble.**

This is what I have for my configuration method in the startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    CookieAuthenticationOptions options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieName = "MyCookieName",
        CookiePath = "/cookiePath",
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
    };
    // Not relevant how this module is made. It helps with
    SessionAuthenticationModule module = this.CreateModule();
    app.Use(typeof(MyCookieAuthenticationMiddleware), app, options, module);

    WsFederationConfiguration fedConfig = new WsFederationConfiguration();
    fedConfig.Issuer = "https://mySTS.com/NotRealUrl/";
    SecurityTokenHandlerCollection handlerCollection = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection(new List<SecurityTokenHandler>() { new SamlSecurityTokenHandler() });
    WsFederationAuthenticationOptions wsFederationOptions = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Configuration = fedConfig,
        Wtrealm = "http://localhost/MyApp/NotRealUrl",
        Wreply = "https://mySTS.com/NotRealUrl/Login",
        SecurityTokenHandlers = handlerCollection,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
    };
    app.Use(typeof(MyWsFederationAuthenticationMiddleware), app, wsFederationOptions);
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.Use<MyMiddleware>();
}
```

The part up to `app.Use(typeof(MyCookieAuthenticationMiddleware), app, options, module);` **works fine**. That is, when the cookie is there, I use my custom cookie authentication middleware (`MyCookieAuthenticationMiddleware`) to generate the `AuthenticationTicket`.

The part that **doesn't work** is the WsFederation authentication middleware part. I created my own middleware for this (`MyWsFederationAuthenticationMiddleware`) so that I could take a look at what's going on since doing `app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsFederationOptions)` directly wasn't working for me. I am looking at the source code for [`WsFederationAuthenticationHandler.cs`](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation/WsFederationAuthenticationHandler.cs) to guide me, but I'm still confused about some overall concepts.

**Questions**

1. I think I know what the general flow should be (what I numbered at
   the top), but I'm not sure how this translates exactly to the
   middleware pipeline. If I don't have a cookie, then I find this out
   in `AuthenticateCoreAsync()` in `MyCookieAuthenticationHandler`. But
   at what point do I redirect this to the STS to get the SAML token?
   Do I just wait for the pipeline to hit `AuthenticateCoreAsync()` in
   `MyWsFederationAuthenticationHandler`, and if the user is not
   authenticated, then get the token?
2. How do I actually *tell* the pipeline that it needs to get the token
   from the STS? Looking again at
   [`WsFederationAuthenticationHandler.cs`](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation/WsFederationAuthenticationHandler.cs), it seems like their
   implementation of `ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()` might be doing
   what I want? More specifically, if it's a 401 status code then make
   a `WsFederationMessage` and redirect to the STS using that message?
3. Assuming I can actually get the STS to return the token I want,
   where in the pipeline does it return to?

Thanks and sorry for the sort of long post.

**Update 1**

I forgot to mention, when I run my code using `app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsFederationOptions)` (instead of my own `MyWsFederationAuthenticationMiddleware`), I get back a 400 "bad request - request too long" error. The URL is very long and looks like it contains various query parameters, including wtrealm, wctx, wa, and wreply, each of which contains url encoded strings. Looks like wctx is the really long one. I imagine it's some base64 encoded object. Unfortunately I don't really know what's going on.

Comment: If you like to debug the flow it is not necessary to write an own Middleware(wrapper). The class WsFederationAuthenticationOptions provides the possibility to hook into the wsfed authentication. You can set the notifications property to a new instance of WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications.

Comment: Do you have also an username/password login with the cookie? Or only WsFed?

Comment: @DennisK Yep, there's a username/password login. I'm not sure what you're suggesting exactly with your first comment. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You wrote:
"I created my own middleware for this (MyWsFederationAuthenticationMiddleware) so that I could take a look at what's going on".
I just want to mention that there is an other way for this in the WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.Notifications (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.wsfederation.wsfederationauthenticationnotifications(v=vs.113).aspx )

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that's what those notifications are for. Thank you, I'll try making use of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is, that both Middlewares have the `AuthenticationMode` `Active`

You should change the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType` to the `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType` then set `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationMode` to passive.

I recommend an custom controller. If the user visits this controller you must trigger the Authentication on the `OwinContext.Authentication` manually for the `WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType`  and return an 401. That should trigger the `ApplyResponseChallengeAsync` in the `WsFederationAuthenticationHandler`

In the `SecurityTokenValidated` Method on the `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions.Notifications` you can issue a new AuthTicket with an identity of type `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType`.

Now the identity from the identity provider is converted to a an local identity with cookieauth.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This looks like the right approach, but I'm still confused. Instead of a controller I just have a class that inherits `OwinMiddleware`, with an override on the `Invoke(IOwinContext context)` method to handle requests. By the time this `Invoke` method is called, it has already gone through the authentication pipeline. So if the cookies were there then the user is authenticated and it's all good, but if not I set the response status code to 401. (cont.)

Comment: At this point, `ApplyResponseChallengeAsync` will supposedly be called for `WsFederationAuthenticationHandler` (or do I manually invoke it?). But I'm not sure what happens at that point. Do I just trust that it comes back and authenticates correctly? It's not really clear from the source code what the flow is. Also, wouldn't it then be too late to do what the request wanted? So I'd have to do all this before the `Invoke` method?

Comment: I tried doing what [the answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663773/the-owin-authentication-pipeline-and-how-to-use-katana-middleware-correctly?rq=1) says, but the code in `AuthenticateAllRequests` didn't work for me. It seems like it's an implementation of what you're suggesting.

Comment: Have you tried the following?
Login manually with
`HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);`

and then set the responsestatus to 401.
`return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); `

Comment: I've worked on it a bit more and I'm getting closer, but still stuck. At this point I am able to redirect to the STS and get back the token. I wrote some code for `SecurityTokenReceived` and can see the claims are there. The problem I'm having is I can only set the `AuthenticationTicket` in `SecurityTokenValidated`, and so far I'm having trouble figuring out how to trigger it.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no exception? This behaviour is mostly when you receive the token but the validation of the token failed.

Comment: Oh you're right -- I realized AuthenticatedFailed is being called with the following exception:
`{"ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier\r\n    (\r\n    IsReadOnly = False,\r\n    Count = 1,\r\n    Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityKeyIdentifierClause\r\n    )\r\n'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key."}` I'll try looking into it more.